# After effect how to make zoom effect

Tags: after-effects, zoom

I want to make the text zoom when it passes the red rectangle. I have added the magnify effect, but it's not looking good. I want to make the long list of text from A to Z. And as the word passes or stops at the red rectangle it should zoom. Any suggestion as to how it works and make it good?

[image]

Comment: Hi Atikroshan, I migrated your question to a community that is a better fit for video questions.